# Global variable won't work in searching in one function

Tags: c#, arrays, global

I made a program that gets info in textbox1 and textbox2 after pressing button1. 
If you type in textbox3 and if what you wrote there is same as textbox1 ,After pressing button2 it puts textbox2's text in the label2.text.

But the problem is that it won't put the textbox2.text into label2.text.
Why?

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ozv[] a = new ozv[5];
    int i = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a[i] = new ozv();
        a[i].name = textBox1.Text;
        a[i].id = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        i++;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            a[j] = new ozv();
            if (a[j].name == textBox3.Text)
            {
                label2.Text = a[j].id.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the class I made:

class ozv
    {
        public string name;
        public int id;
    }

Comment: man your statements are really confusing. can you tell the problem clearly and edit the code properly.

Comment: Just did it now. Sorry for that.

Comment: Remove `a[j] = new ozv();` in `button2_Click`

Comment: @Saverio Terracciano
class ozv
    {
        public string name;
        public int id;
    }

Comment: Can you please at least name the buttons and textboxes, and expand 'ozv' name? It will provide bit of context and it's easeier to understand what's your issue.

Comment: @user3330348 Consider Textbox1 as name, Textbox2 as ID, Textbox3 as requested name, Label2 as ID of the requested name.

The OZV is a class. I edited the post and it's there now.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
--->    a[j] = new ozv();
        if (a[j].name == textBox3.Text)
```

You are erasing what you just saved, this is why you are not getting any result.

Also, check that you a[j] instance is defined:

```
if (a[j] != null) && a[j].name == textBox3.Text)
```

You can also `break;` after you find the first matching occurence, to exit the loop earlier.

**Note 1:** you should try going step-by-step into your code, and looking at the variable states. This would really help you debug stuff like that.

**Note 2:** you should consider using a `List<ozv>` so that you can just iterate over it without having to handle nulls.

Comment: After doing what you said, "Null reference error" appeared on "if (a[j].name == textBox3.Text)" line. what should I do now????

Comment: Updated answer: please try going in debug, step by step for simple things like that. This will help you in the long term.

Comment: Didn't work. If I remove the For cycle it'll work. What should I do to make it work with For Cycle?

Comment: It depends: what is the error, when you go step by step, what is the state of the variables? Can you update your question with the code you have now?

Comment: currently I have this code:
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ozv[] a = new ozv[5];
        int i = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a[i] = new ozv();
            a[i].name = textBox1.Text;
            a[i].id = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            i++;
        }

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                a[j] = new ozv();
                //if (a[j].name == textBox3.Text)
                if ((a[j] != null) &&( a[j].name == textBox3.Text))
                {
                    label2.Text = a[j].id.ToString();
                }
                j++;
           }
        }
    }

Comment: AND THE CLASS:

class ozv
    {
        public string name;
        public int id;
    }