# Global array reference error

Tags: c#, arrays, global

I made a program that gets info in textBox1 and textBox2 after pressing button1. If you type in textBox3 and if what you wrote there is same as textBox1 ,After pressing button2 it puts textBox2's text in the label2.Text.

But the problem is that it won't put the textbox2.text into label2.text. Why?

Here's the code:

```
ozv[] a = new ozv[5];
int i = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    a[i] = new ozv();
    a[i].name = textBox1.Text;
    a[i].id = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    i++;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] != null) && a[j].name == textBox3.Text)
        {
            label2.Text = a[j].id.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the class I made:

```
class ozv 
{ 
  public string name; 
  public int id; 
}
```

when I delete the for cycle, it works fine but when I put it back in the code, the problem occurs again.

Comment: no it's not. but it's C#.

Comment: then it should be winforms?

Comment: Please don't use names button1, button2 etc. Very bad programming

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Is an unhandled exception after the sixth click on button1 really what you want to achieve?

Comment: You've posted an almost exactly the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862876/global-variable-wont-work-in-searching-in-one-function). First, improve your code so that names of your variable carry meaningful information, instead of posting duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are iterating for loop more number of times than you actually incremented "i" by clicking button1.

so take the length of array 'a' and use its length in your for loop.

ex:

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
instead of for (int j = 0; j <5; j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild Guess:

I think the for loop is problem. Its throwing `IndexOutOfArrayException` I suppose.

Try this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] != null) && a[j].name == textBox3.Text)
        {
            label2.Text = a[j].id.ToString();
        }
    }
```